# How can I block a k8s service (pod) from accessing an external azure redis?

Tags: istio-sidecar, chaos

I want to do chaos testing, and I want to inject azure redis failure.
So, I need to block my service pod to access the azure redis on port 90000 (not http/https protocol). I tried the networkPolicy, AuthorizationPolicy, but both didn't work.
Also tried the ServiceEntry, it can change the dns to a fake ipaddress, but after I remove the serviceEntry, the redisclient in my service can't find it and can't restore, so it looks like the serviceentry can't satisfy my requirement.
I tried AuthorizationPolicy to block the access from pod to pod, it worked fine.
So can I use AuthorizationPolicy to implement it? I tried the below yaml, it didn't work:
apiVersion: security.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: AuthorizationPolicy
metadata:
name: restrict-by-ip
namespace: my namespace
spec:
selector:
matchLabels:
app: myapp
action: DENY
rules:

- to:

  - operation:
    ports: ["9000"]
    hosts: ["redishost"]

Who can give some comments? Thanks!